# Filter pcaps containing a MAC address substring

Tags: wireshark, tshark

The script (macOS) is called as such:

```
./Sharksort <all or part of wlan.addr> file-name
example: ./Sharkesort 42:80 Store-1-pass1.pcapng
```

The output should be all traffic to/from clients containing `42:80` in their hardware address.

```
for stream in tshark -r $2 -Y "wlan.addr contains $1";
do
  tshark -r $2 -w client-$1.pcapng;
done
```

I am getting the following:

```
tshark: An error occurred while writing to the file "client-42:80.pcapng": Internal error.
tshark: An error occurred while writing to the file "client-42:80.pcapng": Internal error.
tshark: An error occurred while writing to the file "client-42:80.pcapng": Internal error.
```

The output file contains only the 1st few packets.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't `tshark -r $2 -w client-$1.pcapng` the same as `cp $2 client-$1.pcapng`? What's your pcap's format (libpcap, pcapng, etc.)?

Comment: pcapng.  How does cp extract data from a .pcapng file?   tshark reads the file and extracts the filter

Comment: able to rip out the client details as long as the output is not .pcapng. this script rips out the data fine for csv format.  tshark  -ntu -r $1  -Y "wlan.addr contains $2"  -E header=y -T fields -E separator=',' -e frame.number -e radiotap.mactime  -e frame.time_delta -e radiotap.channel.freq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -e wlan.sa -e wlan.ra -e _ws.col.Info > client-$2.csv && open client-$2.csv

Comment: tshark  -ntu -r $1  -Y "wlan.addr contains $2"  -E header=y -T fields -E separator=',' -e frame.number -e radiotap.mactime  -e frame.time_delta -e radiotap.channel.freq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -e wlan.sa -e wlan.ra -e _ws.col.Info > client-$2.csv && open client-$2.csv

Comment: You're not specifying any filter in `tshark -r $2 -w client-$1.pcapng`. As far as I can see, it's the same as just copying the file.

Comment: so, then this for stream in tshark -r $2 -Y "wlan.addr contains $1";
do
  tshark -r $2  -Y "wlan.addr contains $1 -w client-$1.pcapng;
done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the `for` loop?  Why not just do this?

```
tshark -r $2 -Y "wlan.addr contains $1" -w client-$1.pcapng
```

Comment: tshark: An error occurred while writing to the file "client-29:4B.pcapng": Internal error.   I can run it manually as a 1 liner, but fails when I put it in a script

Comment: I can script it all day just fine when I don't use the -w option. but that does not write out the headers

Comment: For the heck of it, can you try changing the filename to just `-w client.pcapng` to see if *that* works?

Comment: I assume you have permission to write the file in the directory you're trying to write it to?

Comment: yes, it is in my home directory.  Writing to a file without the -w option works fine

Comment: Any more information you can provide?  What version of `tshark`?  What version of OS?  If you're not running the latest version of `tshark`, I'd recommend upgrading if possible.  Stable 2.4.1 was just released **today**.

Comment: tshark -v
TShark (Wireshark) 2.4.0 (v2.4.0-0-g9be0fa5)

Running on Mac OS X 10.12.6, build 16G29 (Darwin 16.7.0), with Intel(R) Core(TM)
i7-6567U CPU @ 3.30GHz (with SSE4.2), with 16384 MB of physical memory, with
locale en_US.UTF-8, with libpcap version 1.8.1 -- Apple version 67.60.1, with
GnuTLS 3.4.17, with Gcrypt 1.7.7, with zlib 1.2.8.

Built using llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build
2336.9.00).
installed via wireshark.org pkg for macOS

Comment: will pull down 2.4.1 and see.  no mention in rel notes about tshark though

Comment: In case it's a bug with writing pcapng files, you could try to force the output file to be written in the old pcap format using the `-F pcap` option.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This work now.   had to add the -F pcap before the -w option. ---  tshark -r $2 -Y "wlan.addr contains $1" -F pcap -w client-$1.pcapng

Comment: Nice!  Since it appears you've encountered a bug with writing pcapng files on macos with Wireshark version 2.4.0, I'd recommend opening a Wireshark bug report for this.  (Well, you might want to test with 2.4.1 first, just in case it's been fixed already and because most likely that's one of the first things the Wireshark developers might ask you to do.)  

https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/

Comment: Tested 2.4.1, still have the issue.  Will file a bug, as -F pcap works, but -F pcapng does not

Comment: OK, it looks like this is being tracked as Wireshark Bug 14027: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14027

Answer (score 0):

the -F option before the -w option is key